# SpringBoot: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' : no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm developing a management software for resturant. I'm using Java Spring Boot for back end and JavaFX for the front end. I'm using Unirest library for the API REST.
I have an Ordination class (in my project called "Ordinazione").

This is the version in Front End:

```
package com.example.ratatouille23.Model;

import com.example.ratatouille23.Model.DTO.OrdinazioneDTO;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Ordinazione {

    private String idTavolo;

    private boolean evasa;

    private Map<Piatto, InfoOrdine> infoPiatto;

    public Ordinazione(String idTavolo){
        this.idTavolo = idTavolo;
        this.infoPiatto = new HashMap<>();
        this.evasa = false;
    }

    public Ordinazione(){
        infoPiatto = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void incrementaQuantitaPiatto(Piatto piatto) {
        if (infoPiatto.containsKey(piatto)){
            InfoOrdine info = infoPiatto.get(piatto);
            int quantity = info.getQuantity();
            info.setQuantity(quantity+1);
            infoPiatto.put(piatto, info);
        } else {
            InfoOrdine info = new InfoOrdine(1, StatoOrdine.DA_PREPARARE);
            infoPiatto.put(piatto, info);
        }
    }

    public void decrementaQuantitaPiatto(Piatto piatto) {
        if (infoPiatto.containsKey(piatto)) {
            InfoOrdine info = infoPiatto.get(piatto);
            int quantity = info.getQuantity();
            if (quantity>1){
                info.setQuantity(quantity-1);
                infoPiatto.put(piatto, info);
            } else {
                infoPiatto.remove(piatto);
            }

        }
    }

    public void aggiungiPiatto(Piatto piatto, int quantita) {
        InfoOrdine info = new InfoOrdine(quantita, StatoOrdine.DA_PREPARARE);
        infoPiatto.put(piatto, info);
    }

    public void setStatoInPreparazione(Piatto piatto){
        InfoOrdine info = this.infoPiatto.get(piatto);
        info.setStato(StatoOrdine.IN_PREPARAZIONE);
        this.infoPiatto.put(piatto, info);
    }

    public void setStatoCompletato(Piatto piatto){
        InfoOrdine info = this.infoPiatto.get(piatto);
        info.setStato(StatoOrdine.COMPLETATO);
        this.infoPiatto.put(piatto, info);
    }

    //

    public String getIdTavolo() {
        return idTavolo;
    }

    public void setIdTavolo(String idTavolo) {
        this.idTavolo = idTavolo;
    }

    public Map<Piatto, InfoOrdine> getPiattiOrdinazione() {
        return infoPiatto;
    }

    public boolean getStato() {
        return evasa;
    }

    public boolean isEvasa() {
        return evasa;
    }

    public void setEvasa(boolean evasa) {
        this.evasa = evasa;
    }

    public Map<Piatto, InfoOrdine> getInfoPiatto() {
        return infoPiatto;
    }

    public void setInfoPiatto(Map<Piatto, InfoOrdine> infoPiatto) {
        this.infoPiatto = infoPiatto;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tavolo: " + idTavolo +
                "\n\n" + infoPiatto;
    }

    // Inner classes

    public class InfoOrdine{

        private int quantity;
        private StatoOrdine stato;

        public InfoOrdine(int quantity, StatoOrdine stato) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.stato = stato;
        }

        public InfoOrdine(int quantity){
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.stato = StatoOrdine.DA_PREPARARE;
        }

        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        public StatoOrdine getStato() {
            return stato;
        }

        public void setStato(StatoOrdine stato) {
            this.stato = stato;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return  " x" + quantity + "\n";

        }

    }

    public enum StatoOrdine{
        DA_PREPARARE,
        IN_PREPARAZIONE,
        COMPLETATO;
    }
}
```

This is OrdinazioneDTO:

```
package com.example.ratatouille23.Model.DTO;

import com.example.ratatouille23.Model.Ordinazione;
import com.example.ratatouille23.Model.Piatto;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class OrdinazioneDTO {

   private String idTavolo;
//    private boolean evasa;
   private Map<Piatto, Ordinazione.InfoOrdine> infoPiatto;

   public OrdinazioneDTO(String idTavolo){
       this.idTavolo = idTavolo;
       this.infoPiatto = new HashMap<>();
//        this.evasa = false;
   }

   public OrdinazioneDTO(){
       infoPiatto = new HashMap<>();
   }

   // Getter and Setter here

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "Tavolo: " + idTavolo +
               "\n\n" + infoPiatto;
   }


}
```

This is the Ordinazione's class in back end:

```
package com.springone3.demo.Entity;

import com.springone3.demo.Controller.PiattoController;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@Entity
@Table
public class Ordinazione {


    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "ordinazione_sequence",
            sequenceName = "ordinazione_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "ordinazione_sequence"
    )
    private Long idOrdinazione;

    private String idTavolo;

    @OneToMany
    Map<Piatto, InfoOrdine> infoPiatto;

    private boolean evasa = false;

    public Ordinazione(Long idOrdinazione, String idTavolo) {
        this.idOrdinazione = idOrdinazione;
        this.idTavolo = idTavolo;
        this.infoPiatto = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public String getidTavolo() {
        return idTavolo;
    }

    public void setidTavolo(String idTavolo) {
        this.idTavolo = idTavolo;
    }

    public boolean isEvasa() {
        return evasa;
    }

    public void setEvasa(boolean evasa) {
        this.evasa = evasa;
    }

    public Ordinazione() {
    }

    public Long getIdOrdinazione() {
        return idOrdinazione;
    }

    public void setIdOrdinazione(Long idOrdinazione) {
        this.idOrdinazione = idOrdinazione;
    }

    public Map<Piatto, InfoOrdine> getInfoPiatto() {
        return infoPiatto;
    }

    public void setInfoPiatto(Map<Piatto, InfoOrdine> infoPiatto) {
        this.infoPiatto = infoPiatto;
    }

    public void aggiungiPiatto(Piatto piatto, Integer quantity) {
        InfoOrdine info = new InfoOrdine(quantity, InfoOrdine.StatoOrdine.DA_PREPARARE);
        infoPiatto.put(piatto, info);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "idTavolo: " + idTavolo +
                "\n\n" + infoPiatto;
    }

    @Entity
    @Table
    public static class InfoOrdine {

        @Id
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @MapsId("idOrdinazione")
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_ordinazione")
        private Ordinazione ordinazione;

        @ManyToOne
        @MapsId("idPiatto")
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_piatto")
        private Piatto piatto;
        private int quantity;
        private InfoOrdine.StatoOrdine stato;

        public InfoOrdine(int quantity, InfoOrdine.StatoOrdine stato) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.stato = stato;
        }

        public InfoOrdine() {
        }

       // Getter and Setter here 

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return  " x" + quantity + "\n";

        }

        public enum StatoOrdine {
            DA_PREPARARE,
            IN_PREPARAZIONE,
            COMPLETATO;
        }

    }
}
```

The DTO's version in back end is equal to front end.

When i call the confirm button in the front end, i call this method:

```
 public void onBtnConfermaOrdinazioneClicked() {
        
       // other code
            
            OrdinazioneDTO ordinazioneDTO = new OrdinazioneDTO();
            ordinazioneDTO.setIdTavolo(ordinazione.getIdTavolo());
            ordinazioneDTO.setInfoPiatto(ordinazione.getInfoPiatto());
            ordinazioneDAO.sendOrdinazione(ordinazioneDTO);
            resetOrdinazione();
        }
    }
```

In front end i have this implementation of DAO'is interface for Ordinazione:

```
package com.example.ratatouille23.Model.DAO.DAOImplUnirest;

import com.example.ratatouille23.Model.DAO.DAOInterface.OrdinazioneDAO;
import com.example.ratatouille23.Model.DTO.OrdinazioneDTO;
import com.example.ratatouille23.Model.Ordinazione;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class OrdinazioneDAOImplUnirest implements OrdinazioneDAO {

    // other code for methods 

    @Override
    public void sendOrdinazione(OrdinazioneDTO ordinazione) {

        try {
            HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ordinazione/postOrdinazione")
                    .header("accept", "application/json")
                    .field("idTavolo", ordinazione.getIdTavolo())
                    .field("infoPiatto", ordinazione.getInfoPiatto())
                    .asJson();
            System.out.println("InfoPiatto: " + ordinazione.getInfoPiatto());
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```

This is the OrdinazioneController's backend:

```
package com.springone3.demo.Controller;

import com.springone3.demo.Entity.Categoria;
import com.springone3.demo.Entity.DTO.OrdinazioneDTO;
import com.springone3.demo.Entity.Ordinazione;
import com.springone3.demo.Service.OrdinazioneService;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/ordinazione")

public class OrdinazioneController {

    @Autowired
    private final OrdinazioneService ordinazioneService;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public OrdinazioneController(OrdinazioneService ordinazioneService) {
        this.ordinazioneService = ordinazioneService;
    }

    // other GET methods

    @PostMapping(path = "/postOrdinazione")
    public void sendOrdinazione(OrdinazioneDTO ordinazioneDaSalvare){
        System.out.println("Il DTO è così: " + ordinazioneDaSalvare.getInfoPiatto());
        Ordinazione ordinazione = modelMapper.map(ordinazioneDaSalvare, Ordinazione.class);
        ordinazione.setEvasa(false);
        System.out.println("L'entity è così: " + ordinazione.getInfoPiatto());
        ordinazioneService.sendOrdinazione(ordinazione);
    }


}
```

This is the Serice:

```
@Service
public class OrdinazioneService {

    @Autowired
    private final OrdinazioneRepository ordinazioneRepository;

    @Autowired
    private final InfoOrdineRepository infoOrdineRepository;

    public OrdinazioneService(OrdinazioneRepository ordinazioneRepository, InfoOrdineRepository infoOrdineRepository) {
        this.ordinazioneRepository = ordinazioneRepository;
        this.infoOrdineRepository = infoOrdineRepository;
    }


    public void sendOrdinazione(Ordinazione ordinazione) {
        ordinazioneRepository.save(ordinazione);
        ArrayList<Piatto> listaPiatti = (ArrayList<Piatto>) ordinazione.getInfoPiatto().keySet();

        ArrayList<Ordinazione.InfoOrdine> listaInfo = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Piatto piatto: listaPiatti){
            Ordinazione.InfoOrdine io = new Ordinazione.InfoOrdine();
            io.setOrdinazione(ordinazione);
            io.setPiatto(piatto);
            io.setQuantity(io.getQuantity());
            io.setStato(io.getStato());
            listaInfo.add(io);
        }

        infoOrdineRepository.saveAll(listaInfo);

    }
```

When i try to execute a post request in my GUI, this is the error that i obtain on back end side:

```
WARN 9248 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public void com.springone3.demo.Controller.OrdinazioneController.sendOrdinazione(com.springone3.demo.Entity.DTO.OrdinazioneDTO): [Field error in object 'ordinazioneDTO' on field 'infoPiatto': rejected value [{Salmone= x1<EOL>}]; codes [typeMismatch.ordinazioneDTO.infoPiatto,typeMismatch.infoPiatto,typeMismatch.java.util.Map,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [ordinazioneDTO.infoPiatto,infoPiatto]; arguments []; default message [infoPiatto]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'infoPiatto'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'infoPiatto': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]] ]
```

}

I really don't know how to resolve this. Any helps?

Comment: Please show the code for your backend that is receiving the post.

Comment: @grekier Thanks for notice me, i edit the post with Controller and Service for Ordinazione.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Map object (infoPiatto) is not converted correctly when it is sent through Unirest `.field()`.

I believe that it probably is sent using toString on the Map which cannot be mapped to a converter on the server side.

I think that using the DTO object directly is probably the best solution for you

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ordinazione/postOrdinazione")
                    .header("accept", "application/json")
                    .body(ordinazione)
                    .asJson();
```

after adding one of the mapper. See http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/#object-mappers